# Gnuplot + bash script

Tags: bash, sed, gnuplot

I have some problems with the following:

I would like to plot many data files, and I found a more or less good script for that

```
#! /bin/bash
ls *.data | sed "s/.data//" > list
for i in `cat list` ; do
   sed -e "s/INPUTFILE/$i/" -e "s/OUTPUTFILE/$i/" \
    plot.gnu | gnuplot
done
rm list
```

plot.gnu

```
set term postscript enhanced color
set output 'OUTPUTFILE.eps'
set title 'OUTPUTFILE'
p 'INPUTFILE.data' u 1:2 w l
```

But I have problem with this part

```
for i in `cat list` ; do
       sed -e "s/INPUTFILE/$i/" -e "s/OUTPUTFILE/$i/" \
        plot.gnu | gnuplot
    done
```

somehow it cannot update the plot.gnu file as it should be... This sed command does not work properly...

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems you solved the issue - would you mind marking the valid answer or add your own answer and mark this as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try

```
for i in `cat list` ; do
   cat plot.gnu | sed "s/\(INPUTFILE\|OUTPUTFILE\)/$i/g" | gnuplot
done
```

Cheers

Comment: You can avoid both calls to `cat`: `while read i ; do sed "s/\(INPUTFILE\|OUTPUTFILE\)/$i/g" plot.gnu | gnuplot ; done < list`.

Comment: I get this error messages:                                            sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @user1116360: `$i` probably contains `/`. Use a different regex separator, for example `:` (supposed `$i` never contains it): `s:\(INPUTFILE\|OUTPUTFILE\):$i:g`.

Comment: This was the problem, the regex separator. Maybe, I should have mentioned that {i} contains the full path of the file, i.e. contains {/}'s. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using `here-document` makes the code even more clear.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat list`
do
    gnuplot <<_EOF_
    set term postscript enhanced color
    set output '$i.eps'
    set title '$i'
    p '$i.data' u 1:2 w l
_EOF_
done
```