# Gnuplot + bash script -- ver 2

Tags: bash, shell, gnuplot

I am just wondering how should I use the previous posted script (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666118/572616) question) in plotting many files at the same time, i.e. some kind of multiplot cases...

I would like to replace this with a better one, which knows this multiplot property:

```
for i in `cat ./data.list`
 do 
   cat ./plot.gnu | sed "s:\(INPUTFILE\|OUTPUTFILE\):$i:g" | gnuplot
 done
```

The plot.gnu is almost the same as before, but we need to modify it in a proper way somehow with taking into account the multiplot requirement:

```
set term postscript enhanced color
set output 'OUTPUTFILE.eps'
set title 'OUTPUTFILE'

set multiplot layout 2,2
p 'INPUTFILE-1.data' u 1:2 w l
p 'INPUTFILE-2.data' u 1:2 w l
p 'INPUTFILE-3.data' u 1:2 w l
p 'INPUTFILE-4.data' u 1:2 w l
unset multiplot
```

The data.list file contains 4 different files, so the `INPUTFILE-1.data, INPUTFILE-2.data, ...` have to be replaced by them, and finally get one plot.

Can anyone suggest me some more or less nice algorithm, or something for this?

Comment: What do you call that 'multiplot property'?

Comment: Multiplot is just many plot after eachother: p 'INPUTFILE-1.data' u 1:2 w l and p 'INPUTFILE-2.data' u 1:2 w l,...etc The main point is that somehow I have to replace all of the INPUTFILE-1, INPUTFILE-2, ... simultaneously

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. How does the `set multiplot` line affect the following lines?

Comment: can you add a sample expected intermediate output to your posting, it's hard to tell what you need as a final result (not including the actual output of gnuplot). Good luck.

Comment: What are you unsatisfied about in your code? Things seem to work file.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=0
substitutions=
for i in $(<data.list)
 do substitutions+="s:\(INPUTFILE-$((++n))\|OUTPUTFILE\):$i:;"
 done
<plot.gnu sed "$substitutions" | gnuplot
```

Note that output and title will be named after the first input file.